# Electric pressure washers: are type of pump, flow rate, and PSI reliable indicators of duty cycle?

Tags: pump, pressure-washer, flow-rate

I know little about pressure washers but do need to buy one for a project where I'll use the 15-degree nozzle to power-wash decades of grime from several pallets of reclaimed pavers. I'd like to pick the unit by duty-cycle, by how long it would work non-stop before it needed some time to cool down. I would like to avoid units that can be used only for 3-minute stints and then require the same length of time or longer to cool down. But none of the manuals I've seen give any explicit indication of the unit's duty cycle, nothing as clear as "This unit has a 60% duty cycle".  Is there a way to determine the duty cycle from the specifications?

For example, one company's line of electric units, designed to be sold to companies that rent equipment, has **AAA triplex pumps** whereas their consumer models have an **axial cam pump**. Is *type of pump* the best indicator of duty cycle? Or is *flow-rate* an important factor too for determining duty cycle?   Assuming the flow from the mains is able to meet the unit's demand, would a 2GPM unit have a longer —or a shorter— duty cycle than a 1GPM unit if both units were the same amperage and both had the same kind of pump? Would the greater flow rate cool better and thereby offer a longer duty cycle, or does the greater flow rate cause the pump to have to work harder and thereby be quicker to overheat?  And does greater PSI mean the pump has to work harder, so that if your goal was to extend the duty cycle, not to increase the cleaning force, all things being equal, a 2000 PSI unit would be a better choice than a 3000 PSI unit?

Comment: Don't think they do have duty cycles.  The pumps probably do have a life of use time before they wear out, better ones hopefully longer.  Need to be more careful with higher pressures since they can start cutting/breaking/damaging softer materials(windows, weak material, paint) with narrow tips(0degree), pavers should be okay.  Would do in cooler part of the day, 110 in the sun would probably not help the machine or you.

Comment: Used a big one at full pressure to deliberately remove many coats of paint from old transformers prior to repainting. By far the easiest method... Made sure they were off though.

Comment: Think you are thinking of welders, they are the only things I can think of that do have duty cycles.  Talking of pallets, I guess they are not single rows.  Before starting I would lay out the pavers in a single layer, before washing.  The washer(any one) will do a good fast job.  The more powerful ones will probably even turn the pavers over for you.

Comment: I got a cheap electric pressure washer (when I need a big one I rent). It will run for as long as I squeeze the handle, so I guess it is 100% duty cycle. One thing I like about it is that when you release the handle, a small amount of water continues to run through the pump (and wand) keeping things cool when you are not spraying.

Comment: Honestly, I find it hard to believe that you'll actually be using the washer for more than several minutes at a time without stopping the flow of water to adjust your position, your grip on the wand, the pavers, something. I bought a cheap ~$100 electric washer for my deck. I can't go more than a few minutes without stopping the water flow for _some_ sort of movement or adjustment...

Answer (score 2):

No. Type of pump, flow rate and PSI are not reliable indicators of duty cycle on an electric pressure washer. Duty cycle is entirely dependent on the design and quality of the electric motor that drives the pump. All other things being equal, a motor designed for greater heat dissipation and/or with higher temperature insulation will have a higher duty cycle, potentially up to 100%.

Regarding the pump itself, I don't know of any pressure washer pump designs that can't be run at 100% duty cycle. Cold water passing through the pump provides cooling. There may be limits, however, on how long you can run with the motor and water turned on but no water flowing out the nozzle. On one engine-driven pressure washer that I've used, the limit is two minutes. The manual says to release some water out the nozzle to provide pump cooling after two minutes of no-flow, or optionally shut down.

I think your best course of action is to select the pressure washer that you think will do the job, then download a copy of the manual from the manufacturer. Look for any information in the manual about duty cycle or continuous use. I think it's safe to assume that if there is no mention of it, the duty cycle is 100%.

Comment: I've found an electric model with a triplex pump priced at $700 US, positioned between mid-tier consumer ($400) and low-end commercial units ($1100) where the manufacturer says "Continuous-run motor and pump ...  offering the best pressure and flow response in the industry; thermal relief valve purges hot water from pump to cool it down during constant use."

Comment: The models with axial cam pumps tend to have an auto-shutoff feature for when the motor gets too hot, and instruct the consumer to allow the unit cool down for 30 minutes when that happens. Those models are in the $325-$425 range and give no indication of duty cycle other than to imply (by reference to the auto-shutdown feature when they overheat) that the duty cycle isn't going to be continuous. That's the problem: how to know if you're getting a longer duty cycle by spending $425 vs $325.

Comment: @mrblint Re purging hot water, my engine-driven triplex has that feature, but it only releases hot water if you've been running with no flow. When you think about it, a no flow condition is the only time you can possibly build up hot water. I've done extended continuous flow (10+min at a time) and never had a water release. And during pauses, I've always released some water every 2 minutes so the relief valve has never activated. Perhaps the mfr's statement is poorly worded and the relief valve is indeed only for no-flow idling.

Comment: @mrblint Re axial cam with auto-shutoff, see if you can find a diagram of the equipment and locate the auto-shutoff's reset switch. If it's on the motor housing, the auto-shutoff is sensing high temperature in the motor, not the pump. Clearly, if the equipment needs an auto-shutoff feature so as not to burn itself out, it can't be run at 100% duty cycle and it's not for you. So look for a model without that feature.